# Importing typescript module into angular component

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, angular5

I am trying to use a certain library in my component but I seem to be missing a step in including it properly

My component is as follows.  The library in question is geolib

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StationsService } from '../../../services/stations/stations.service';
import { Station } from '../../../classes/station.model';
import 'geolib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pollution',
 templateUrl: './pollution.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./pollution.component.scss']
})
export class PollutionComponent implements OnInit {
private markers: Station[];

constructor(private stationsService: StationsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.stationsService.GetAll().subscribe(
        res => {
            for (let i of res) {
                var t = geolib.computeDestinationPoint({ latitude: i.Lat, longitude: i.Long }, 1234, 90);
            }
            this.markers = res;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

geloibs .d.ts file is as follows

```
declare namespace geolib {    
.....
}
declare module "geolib" {
 export = geolib;
}
```

The tooling doesn't complain and everything compiles but when I run it geolib is not defined.

Comment: have you tried import * as geolib from 'geolib';

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Submit as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: done, glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax to import a module structured this way:

```
import * as geolib from 'geolib';
```